# I am doing a Live Search and then on button click the page refreshes how do I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working on a page where I can search for a name or surname and filter actively (this part works perfectly). Once I have found the relevant record I then need to be able to complete an action using one of four buttons related to the record. All of this needs to work without the page refreshing (I am therefore using ajax). if I do not search and click one of the four buttons it works perfectly and I get an alert at the top of the page without any refresh BUT when I do a search and try the page refreshes and therefore I do not get the alert at the top of the page and my search is cleared.  I have made other submissions before and noone has helped me at all so I am really hoping that this time someone will be able to assist.

I have tried the solutions listed below:

1. Type=Button: for each of the buttons - the button does not work at all in the search option
2. With the above one I have tried including a submit action in the javascript - it still does not work
3. e.stopPropagation(): page still refreshes
4. using $_SESSION['msg']: doesn't show the alert for the non-search option and refreshes the page for the search option so my search is still cleared

My code is as follows:

**The search page**

```
<?php
include("includes/header.php");
if (isset($_GET['event_id'])) {
    $event_id = $_GET['event_id'];
    $event = new Event($con, $userLoggedIn);
    $eventname = $event->getEventName($event_id);
    $table = $event->getTableName($event_id);
    $guest = new Guest($con, $userLoggedIn);
    // echo "<script>console.log(" . $eventname . ")</script>";
}

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $table);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

?>

<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="stats_details column">
        **... code not related to the question**

    </div>

    <div class="main_column column">
        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
            echo  $_SESSION['msg'];
            unset($_SESSION['msg']);
        } ?>
        <div id="message"></div>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <label for="search" class="font-weight-bold lead text-dark">Search Record &nbsp; </label>
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search_text" class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-0 border-primary" placeholder="Search...">
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="cards-list" id="table-data">
            <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                <div class="card m-2">
                    <div class="card-header <?= $row['checkin_guests'] > 0 ? 'success' : 'deep_blue'; ?> text-muted">
                        Guests: <?= $row['total_guests']; ?> | Checkedin: <?= $row['checkin_guests']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-title h3"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>&nbsp;<?= $row['first_name']; ?> <?= $row['last_name']; ?></div>
                        <p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-building" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;<?= $row['company']; ?></p>
                        <p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-at" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;<?= $row['email']; ?></p>
                        <p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;<?= $row['phone']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer default text-muted">
                        <form action="" method="POST" class="action_buttons">
                            <input type="hidden" class="gid" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>">
                            <button class="btn success checkin" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Checkin"><i class="fas fa-user-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn warning" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Checkout" name="Checkout"><i class="fas fa-user-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit" name="Edit"><i class="fas fa-user-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cancel" name="Cancel"><i class="fas fa-user-slash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var event = <?php echo $event_id; ?>;


        
        //live search
        $("#search_text").keyup(function() {
            var search = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'action.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    query: search,
                    event: event
                },

                success: function(response) {
                    $("#table-data").html(response);
                }
            });
        });

        //checkin

        $(".checkin").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#message").html('');
            var $form = $(this).closest(".action_buttons");
            var gid = $form.find(".gid").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'action.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    gid: gid,
                    checkin: 'checkin',
                    event: event
                },

                success: function(response) {
                    $("#message").html(response);
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

***action.php***

```
<?php
require 'config/config.php';
include("includes/classes/User.php");
include("includes/classes/Event.php");
include("includes/classes/Guest.php");

$userLoggedIn = $_SESSION['username'];
$event = new Event($con, $userLoggedIn);
$guest = new Guest($con, $userLoggedIn);


if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
  $output = '';
  $search = $_POST['query'];
  $event_id = $_POST['event'];
  $table = $event->getTableName($event_id);
  $_SESSION['search'] = $search;
  $stmt = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE first_name LIKE '%$search%' OR last_name LIKE '%$search%'");

  if (mysqli_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
      $checked_class = $row['checkin_guests'] > 0 ? "success" : "deep_blue";
      $output .= '
                <div class="card m-2">
                  <div class="card-header ' . $checked_class  . ' text-muted">
                    Guests:' . $row['total_guests'] . ' | Checkedin: ' . $row['checkin_guests'] . '
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-title h3"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>&nbsp;' . $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . '</div>
                    <p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-building" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;' . $row['company'] . '</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-at" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;' . $row['email'] . '</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;' . $row['phone'] . '</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-footer default text-muted">
                    <form action="" method="POST" class="action_buttons">
                    <input type="hidden" class="gid" value="' . $row['id'] . '">
                    <button class="btn success checkin" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Checkin"><i class="fas fa-user-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn warning" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Checkout"><i class="fas fa-user-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit"><i class="fas fa-user-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cancel"><i class="fas fa-user-slash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
                ';
    }
    echo $output;
  } else {
    echo "<h3>No Records Found</h3>";
  }
}

if (isset($_POST['checkin'])) {
  $event_id = $_POST['event'];
  $table = $event->getTableName($event_id);
  $gid = $_POST['gid'];
  $result = $guest->checkin($event_id, $gid);
  /* $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible mt-2">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>Guest ' . $gid . ' Checked In Successfully in ' . $table . ' response: ' . $count . '</strong>
      </div>'; */
  
  echo $result;
}

?>
```

***The guest checkin class***

```
 public function checkin($event_id, $id) {
    $table= $this->event_obj->getTableName($event_id);
    $guest_list_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT checked, checkin_guests FROM " . $table ." WHERE `id`='$id'");
    //echo "<script>console.log(" . $table . ")</script>";
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($guest_list_query);
    //echo "<script>console.log(" . $count . ")</script>";
    /* $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible mt-2">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Guest ' . $id . ' Checked In Successfully in ' . $table . ' response: ' . $count . '</strong>
    </div>'; */
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible mt-2">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Guest ' . $id . ' Checked In Successfully in - response rows: ' . $count . '</strong>
    </div>';
  }
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? If your user reloads the page, he reloads the page - do you want to block this?

Comment: do you mean  $(".checkin").click not work after you search filter?

Comment: @NicoHaase when the page refreshes it means that the search field is cleared and you need to start the search from scratch - also the message does not get shown so the user does not get alerted to what action was completed.

Comment: @RonnySulistio it is not working as I require after the search filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i get from your explanation is, $(".checkin").click not work after you do a search, its because javascript only work once, when all page finish loaded.
when you do search, a new button will appear and javascript not called again to give button check in onclick, thats why your button on click not working.

so i suggest you to using solution no. 1 Type=Button: for each of the buttons
copy your javascript $(".checkin").click, document ready and other function/include that need to copy to make checkin click work to action.php

example: copy this to action.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var event = <?php echo $event_id; ?>;

        //checkin

        $(".checkin").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#message").html('');
            var $form = $(this).closest(".action_buttons");
            var gid = $form.find(".gid").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'action.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    gid: gid,
                    checkin: 'checkin',
                    event: event
                },

                success: function(response) {
                    $("#message").html(response);
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

or

still using solution no 1 type button, then make your javascript onclick as function outside document ready then make button onClick (action.php and search page) to call that function

```
} -> end  document ready 
function checkinButton(){


        var $form = $(this).closest(".action_buttons");
        var gid = $form.find(".gid").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'action.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                gid: gid,
                checkin: 'checkin',
                event: event
            },

            success: function(response) {
                $("#message").html(response);
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                
            }
        });
}
```

Button:

```
<button onClick="checkinButton()" class="btn success checkin" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Checkin"><i class="fas fa-user-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```